# Jupyter Password Not Hashed

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nvidia-jetson-nano

When I try to set up the jupyter notebook password, I don't get a password hash when I open up the jupyter_notebook_config.json file.

This is the output of the json file:

```
{
"NotebookApp": {
  "password": 
 "argon2:$argon2id$v=19$m=10240,t=10,p=8$pcTg1mB/X5a3XujQqYq/wQ$/UBQBRlFdzmEmxs6c2IzmQ"
 }

}
```

I've tried running passwd() from python as well, like in the instructions for **Preparing a hashed password** instructions found [online](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#working-remotely) but it produces the same results as above. No hash.

Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

I'm trying to set up a Jetson Nano in similar fashion to the Deep Learing Institute Nano build. With that build you can run Jupyter Lab remotely so the nano can run headless. I'm trying to do the same things with no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

This is the default algorithm (`argon2`):

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/v6.5.2/notebook/auth/security.py#L23

you can provide a different algorithm like `sha1` if you like:

```
>>> from notebook.auth import passwd
>>> from notebook.auth.security import passwd_check
>>>
>>> password = 'myPass123'
>>>
>>> hashed_argon2 = passwd(password)
>>> hashed_sha1 = passwd(password, 'sha1')
>>> 
>>> print(hashed_argon2)
argon2:$argon2id$v=19$m=10240,t=10,p=8$JRz5GPqjOYJu/cnfXc5MZw$LZ5u6kPKytIv/8B/PLyV/w
>>>
>>> print(hashed_sha1)
sha1:c29c6aeeecef:0b9517160ce938888eb4a6ec9ca44e3a31da9519
>>> 
>>> passwd_check(hashed_argon2, password)
True
>>>
>>> passwd_check(hashed_sha1, password)
True
```

Check whether you don't have a different Jupyter server running on your machine. It happened to me that I was trying over and over a password on port `8888` while my intended server was on port `8889`.

Another time, Anaconda started a server on `localhost:8888`, and I was trying to reach a mapped port from a docker container, also on port 8888, and the only way to access was actually on `0.0.0.0:8888`.