# How can I configure a Jupyter notebook password in a YAML file?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, yaml, kubectl

I would like to configure the password to my Jupyter notebook in the deployment.yaml file. I run this file with kubectl. The notebook starts up fine, but the password is not set. How can I improve the yaml file to configure a password?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: minimal-notebook
  labels:
    app: minimal-notebook
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: minimal-notebook
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: minimal-notebook
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: minimal-notebook
        image: jupyter/minimal-notebook:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8888
        args: ["start-notebook.sh", "--NotebookApp.password='sha1:[password]'"]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the space “[password]” on your code, you need to enter a hashed password to use for web authentication, you can prepare a hashed password manually, using the function “from notebook.auth import passwd; passwd()” in a python/IPython shell; you can use the next links as a guide to prepare the hashed password [link 1](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html) [link 2](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#preparing-a-hashed-password) where is the next example:

```
from notebook.auth import passwd
passwd()
Enter password:
Verify password:
Out[2]: 'sha1:67c9e60bb8b6:9ffede0825894254b2e042ea597d771089e11aed'
```

If you prefer you can also use an algorithm using the next links [link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65498980/15887270) [link 4](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/notebook/auth/security.py#L24)